# Prisma Relations Errors

Tags: mysql, next.js, prisma

I'm attempting to create a model in Prisma, but I'm running into errors when adding relations. To give you a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish, allow me to explain.

My goal is to create a User table that contains basic information about each user. I also want to create two additional tables (Driver and Client) that are related to the User table. In the User table, there's a role that indicates whether the user is a driver or a client. When I access a user (for example, if they're a driver), I want to be able to retrieve all of their data, including their driver information (such as car model, car miles, and revenue).
here is my schema :

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id            Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstname     String
  lastname      String
  avatar        String
  phone_number  Int
  email         String    @unique
  password      String
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  emailVerified DateTime?
  Role          UserType  @default(Client)
  driver        Driver?   @relation(name: "DriverRelation", fields: [driverId], references: [id])
  driverId      Int?
  client        Client?   @relation(fields: [clientId], references: [id])
  clientId      Int?
}

enum UserType {
  Client
  Driver
}

model Client {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  company_name  String  @unique
  budget        Decimal
  users         User[]

  @@map("clients")
}

model Driver {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId      Int     @unique
  revenue     Decimal
  car_model   String
  car_miles   String
  user        User?   @relation(name: "driverUser", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  @@map("drivers")
}
```